# A non piece-wise bijective function between $\mathbb{R}$ and $[0,\infty)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I found the piece-wise bijection:

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x=1 \\ 
e^{x-1} & x \in \{2,3,4,...\} \\
e^{x} & x \in \mathbb{R}- \mathbb{N}
\end{cases}$

But can we find a non piece-wise bijection?

I tried the composition idea:

$f_{1}:(0,1] \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ and $f_{2}:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0,1]$

I know $f_{1}=\text{sech}^{-1}(x)$ but I couldn't find a non piece-wise bijection $f_{2}$.

Is there a non piece-wise bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: The problem is that there is not a rigorous definition of "piecewise function". For instance, is the function
$$
|x|=\begin{cases}
x &\text{if $x\ge0$} \\
-x &\text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
piecewise? What about the function $\sqrt{x^2}$? Do you see the issue?

Comment: The correct terminology is to say that a function is *defined* piecewise, i.e. in a particular passage of text, the values of a function are given by considering different cases.

Comment: function is piece-wise if it is separated by cases .

Comment: Then by your definition, the answer is a very trivial, "no" because **all** functions are separated by cases. For example, consider the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases}-|x|& x< 0\\0&x = 0\\|x|&x > 0\end{cases}$$Now some people might mistake $f(x) = x$ as not being piecewise, but as I've just demonstrated, it is.

Comment: @PaulSinclair  A piecewise function is a function that is defined on a sequence of intervals and is built from more than one function. The function x in your writing not considered piece wise because -abs(x)=--x=x and abs(x)=x and x=0=x

Comment: Your attempted clarification of what a piecewise function is doesn't disqualify my definition of $f(x)$ at all. It expresses the identity function as  defined on a sequence of intervals and built from three different functions, namely the constant function $0$ and the two functions $|x|$ and $-|x|$. You are going to have to accept that your concept of a "piecewise function" is flawed. As Joe has already said, "piecewise" is a description the *definition*, not the function itself.

Comment: Also, your requrement of being defined on *intervals* is far too restrictive. For example, this wonderful and famouse function has a very curious property:$$h(x) = \begin{cases}0&x \notin \Bbb Q\\\max\left\{\frac 1p\ \middle |\ px \in \Bbb N\right\}&x \in\Bbb Q\end{cases}$$ where $\Bbb N$ is the natural numbers and $\Bbb Q$ is the rational numbers. A function is a rule that provides a unique well-defined output for each input. This is a concept that is much broader than you currently think.

Comment: @PaulSinclair $h(x)$ is interesting in my opinion, but where can I find more about it?

Comment: @PaulSinclair What suggestions do you have to improve my question? and in my opinion your different three functions are just another way to write $x$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair And it is important to say I didn't mean any disqualifications to your definition of $x$ as piece wise function, my intention was to clarify the purpose of my question.

Comment: Of course my three functions are another way to write $x$. That was the point. It is only one of infinitely many possible piecewise definitions. $h(x)$ is a common example found in introductory real analysis courses. The curious property is that it is continuous at every irrational $x$, but discontinuous at every rational $x$. For your question, accept that "piecewise function" just isn't definable. Probably the closest concept to what you are after is a *continuous* bijection. The answer for that is "No, there is no continuous bijection between those sets".

Comment: Looking at the definition of $h(x)$, I notice I failed to say $p \in \Bbb N$. The idea is that $x = \frac qp$, with $q$ and $p$ relatively prime - i.e., the simplest expression of $x$ as a ratio of two integers. Since that $p$ is the smallest possible denominator, it has the largest inverse - thus the characterization of the value as a maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @PaulSinclair commented, I suppose you are looking for continuous bijection.

Assume $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$ is continuous surjection.
Thus, $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = 0$. Choose $\epsilon > 0$.
Now,
$f$ is continuous $\implies f([x-\epsilon ,x])= [0,a_1]$ and $f([x, x+ \epsilon ])= [0,a_2]$ for some $a_1,a_2 \in [0, \infty)$.
Let $a = \min \{a_1,a_2\}$
Thus, as $f$ is continuous, $\forall y \in (0,a],\ y$ has two preimages $x_1, x_2$;
$x_1 \in [x-\epsilon, x)\ \text{and } x_2 \in (x, x +\epsilon]$

Thus $f$ can't be one one, and subsequently not a bijection